# Format Excel using Access 2010 VBA. My code works the first time.

Tags: excel, ms-access-2010, vba

I'm using Access 2010 VBA to create an Excel worksheet with cols A thru M and an unknown number of rows.  My formatting is simple, changing font, adding borders, col widths, printing options, etc. It runs the first time but if I try it again it returns the following error: "Err = 91 Object variable or With block variable not set". My confusion is that where it errors works the first time it's run but then it won't work anymore. Here is my code:

```
`Option Compare Database
'Option Explicit

'Dim objXLApp         As Excel.Application
'Dim objXLBook        As Excel.Workbook
'Dim objXLSheet       As Excel.Worksheet
'Dim objXLRange       As Object
'Dim xlLastRow        As Long
'Dim xlCell           As String

`Public Sub FormatTaskCalendar(fileIn As String, sheetIn As String)
 On Error GoTo Err_FormatTaskCalendar

        'open the Excel spreadsheet with the exported data
Set objXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        'for testing, make the applicaiton visible
objXLApp.Visible = True
Set objXLBook = objXLApp.Workbooks.Open(fileIn)
        'make the "Orders" worksheet to be the active worksheet
Set objXLSheet = objXLBook.Sheets(sheetIn)
        'find the last used cell in Column "A" (Center)
xlLastRow = objXLSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

        'show the cell borders for entire sheet
With objXLSheet.Range("A1:M" & xlLastRow).Borders
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlThin
End With

With objXLSheet.Range("B1:M" & xlLastRow).Font
    .Name = "Verdana"
    .Size = 11
End With

        'select first row and apply formating
objXLSheet.Activate
objXLSheet.Range("A1:M1").Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 5287936
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.Font.Name = "Verdana"
Selection.Font.Size = 13
Selection.Font.Bold = True
Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
    .WrapText = True
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With

    'freeze the pane so the header row doesn't scroll
objXLSheet.Activate
objXLSheet.Range("A2", "A2").Select
objXLApp.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

'autofit the columns
objXLSheet.Activate
objXLSheet.Range("A1", "M1").Select
objXLSheet.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("B:B").ColumnWidth = 15.5           'Neovia Team Member
Columns("D:D").ColumnWidth = 26.5           'Client Name
Columns("E:E").ColumnWidth = 13             'Renewal Date
Columns("F:F").ColumnWidth = 14.44          'Stage
Columns("G:G").ColumnWidth = 12.7           'Channel
Columns("H:H").ColumnWidth = 36.5           'Task Name
Columns("I:I").ColumnWidth = 12.3           'Task Due Date
Columns("J:J").ColumnWidth = 16             'Task Completion Date
Columns("K:K").ColumnWidth = 14.11          'Days To Complete
Columns("L:L").ColumnWidth = 10.56          'Actual Work Hours
Columns("M:M").ColumnWidth = 15.3           'Comments

        ''do some settings for the page layout when printing
objXLApp.PrintCommunication = True
With objXLSheet.PageSetup
    .Orientation = xlLandscape
    .PrintTitleRows = "$1:$1"
    .PrintTitleColumns = ""
    .LeftHeader = "&""Verdana,Bold""&13page &P of &N"
    .CenterHeader = "&""Verdana,Bold""&13Task Calendar"
    .RightHeader = "&""Verdana,Bold""&13&D&T"
    .LeftFooter = ""
    .CenterFooter = ""
    .RightFooter = ""

    .LeftMargin = objXLApp.InchesToPoints(0.25)
    .RightMargin = objXLApp.InchesToPoints(0.25)
    .TopMargin = objXLApp.InchesToPoints(0.75)
    .BottomMargin = objXLApp.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .HeaderMargin = objXLApp.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .FooterMargin = objXLApp.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = False

End With
objXLApp.PrintCommunication = False

'save the changes
objXLBook.Save
objXLApp.Quit
Set objXLApp = Nothing
```

My code creates and error when it performs this line of code:

```
          'select first row and apply formating
objXLSheet.Activate
objXLSheet.Range("A1:M1").Select
With Selection.Interior
```

I turned the visible property on so I can see it does select A1:M1 but I can't figure out why the next line only works once.  This is my first time trying to format Excel from Access.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have your code commented, I am not sure if you are using Early Binding or Late Binding.

However, Try this. Avoid the use of `.Select`, `Selection` or `.Activate`

Change the lines

```
objXLSheet.Activate
objXLSheet.Range("A1:M1").Select
With Selection.Interior
```

to

```
With objXLSheet.Range("A1:M1").Interior
```

You might also want to see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select/10718179#10718179) link.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I also changed the remaining code to eliminate the use of .Select .Selection and .Activate.  Everything works great except for one line.  I guess I don't know Excel object very well.  I can't figure out how to freezepanes.  Every example I can find uses exactly what you told me not to do.  Could you help me one more time and point me in the right direction.  You also asked about early or late binding.  If I understand correctly I think I'm using early binding in that I have set a reference to "Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library".

Comment: I would in that case suggest you to visit MSDN and search for `Excel Object Library`. It has been very well documented. If you still have questions then I would request you to post the code where you are stuck and then we can take it from there?

Comment: Thanks so much for your help and your rapid response.  I got freezepanes to work.  This is the code I used:
    objXLSheet.Range("A2").Select
    objXLBook.Windows.Application.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
Please let me know if you have a better suggestion.  Thanks again.